# Trying to use .htaccess for www and https redirects

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to get my site to redirect to HTTPS, and I can only seem to get it partially working.

Here's what my .htaccess currently looks like:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule .* /index.php [L]
```

The problem is, is that it's not retaining the URL (virtual path that gets parsed by index.php), so for example, http://blah.com/mypage redirects to https://blah.com

What am I doing wrong?

I also need to ensure www is in place as well, but one step at a time :)

Comment: Welcome to SO and thanks for showing your efforts in your question. Could you please do let us know if your index,php file is present in root path OR in same path where .htaccess file is present? Kindly confirm once.

Comment: it's in the root of the site, same folder as the .htaccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my file works - I just didn't clear my cache. Major oops on my end.

Here's the .htaccess file for those curious:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule .* /index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blah.com$
RewriteRule ^$ https://blah.com/mypage [L,R=301]
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^https://blah.com$
RewriteRule ^$ https://blah.com/mypage [L,R=301]
```

Comment: But that would have to be done for every link on the site (hundreds). These are all virtual paths, so /mypage doesn't exist in the file structure - it's captured in the index.php file that explodes the request uri.